# How do i convert this code to use bootstrap? it has 10 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, grid.mvc

```
<div class="text-center">
    <span class= "container-fluid">    
      @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>    
        columns.Add(foo => foo.IncidentNumber).Titled("Incident Number").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.OpenedBy).Titled("Opened By").SetWidth(110);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.OpenedDate).Titled("Opened Date").SetWidth(110).Sortable(true);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.Environment).Titled("Environment").SetWidth(110).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.AssignedPerson).Titled("Assigned Person").SetWidth(110).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.Description).ToString().Substring(0, 10);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.LatestFeedback).Titled("Latest Feedback").SetWidth(110);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.LatestFeedBackDate).Titled("Latest FeedBack Date").SetWidth(110);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.ServiceManagerStatus).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(foo => foo.ReportBackdate).Titled("ReportBackdate").SetWidth(110);
        columns.Add()
        .Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .RenderValueAs(foo => Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = foo.IncidentID }));
       }).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true)
    </span>
</div>
```

i want to use bootstrap, i am new to MVC and i am not sure how to do it. i want my table to be opened on computer screens as well as cellphones.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first thing first ,Bootstrap has 12 columns for you to divide and there are a few options where you can define the size of the columns on different screens(computer screens,cellphones)

- xs = extra small screens (mobile phones)
- sm = small screens (tablets)
- md = medium screens (some desktops)
- lg = large screens (remaining desktops)

So in  your case ,

`<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">your column</div>`

should do the trick. Hope it helps! :-)